# Using nano in expect scripts

Tags: svn, commit, send, expect, spawn

I am trying to commit to a repository using expect script but when I do commit, nano editor opens and I am not able to control it using the expect script. The code snippet is as follows :

```
spawn sudo svn commit e

expect "password for yesha"

send "1234\r"
```

Now a nano editor opens and I need to save the file using the script only. I tried

```
send "\030"
```

It is the octal code for control X. But it shows the following error

send: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing
"send "\030""
    (file "/home/yesha/Desktop/metadata/scripts/addCommit.exp" line 20)

How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you specify the commit message on the command line and avoid the editor?

```
spawn sudo svn commit -m "this is my commit log message" e
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

> If you do not supply a log message with your commit by using either the --file or --message option, svn will launch your editor for you to compose a commit message.